# Custom filter in Angularjs not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to implement custom filter in Angularjs. But I'm not getting what is the problem in that. Not getting the output as expected. Here is my code:

script.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myModule', []);
myApp.filter("gender", function(){
  return function(gender){
    switch(gender){
      case 1 : return 'Male';
      case 2 : return 'Female';
    }
  }
});

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope){
var employees = [
    { name : 'Raghu', gender : '1', salary : 84000.779 },
    { name : 'Anil', gender : '1', salary : 78000 },
    { name : 'Ramya', gender : '2', salary : 118000 },
    { name : 'Shwetha', gender : '2', salary : 68000 },
    { name : 'Chethan', gender : '1', salary : 168000 }
];
$scope.employees = employees;
```

});

page.html

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="myController">
        <h1>Angular Example Ten</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                    <td>{{ employee.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.gender | gender }}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.salary }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is there any error in console?

Comment: It would be helpful if you mentioned what output you were getting as well.

Comment: no errors, the gender column is empty..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the numeric cases to string values :

```
case '1' : return 'Male';
case '2' : return 'Female';
```

Because `1 !== "1"`.

```js
console.log('1 !== "1" ::::', 1 !== "1"); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

the number you are passing is string not an integer. change the switch case numbers to string

```
switch(gender){
      case "1" : return 'Male';
      case "2" : return 'Female';
    }
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myModule', []);
myApp.filter("gender", function(){
  return function(gender){
  debugger
    switch(gender){
      case "1" : return 'Male';
      case "2" : return 'Female';
    }
  }
});

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope){
var employees = [
    { name : 'Raghu', gender : '1', salary : 84000.779 },
    { name : 'Anil', gender : '1', salary : 78000 },
    { name : 'Ramya', gender : '2', salary : 118000 },
    { name : 'Shwetha', gender : '2', salary : 68000 },
    { name : 'Chethan', gender : '1', salary : 168000 }
];
$scope.employees = employees;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">
        <h1>Angular Example Ten</h1>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                    <td>{{ employee.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.gender | gender }}</td>
                    <td>{{ employee.salary }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the numeric cases to string values :

```
switch(gender){     
    case '1' : return 'Male';
    case '2' : return 'Female';
default: return 'Male';
}
```

You should convert that to string and also have the default result.

[AngularJS Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)